# Geofencing doesn't work?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, geofencing, android-geofence

So I've been trying simple geofencing applications from the internet but none of them seems to work. In the following example a notification should be triggered when the longitude and the latitude of the phone meet the longitude and the latitude defined in the constants class. I tested it with the emulator but when I change the emulator gps coordinates accordingly, nothing happens.
According to the documentation there are some possible reasons for alerts not working as expected:

- Accurate location isn't available inside your geofence or your
  geofence is too small
- Wi-Fi is turned off on the device.
- There is no reliable network connectivity inside your geofence.
- Alerts can be late.

I get this message on android studio:
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=12VjaB5BNjdIrOD5QVJWLoRwnXEZq6KKB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mH8x.png)

Here is my log:

```
02-01 13:42:09.932 14925-14925/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-01 13:42:09.955 14925-14925/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
02-01 13:42:09.993 14925-14932/? E/zygote: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
02-01 13:42:09.993 14925-14932/? I/zygote: Debugger is no longer active
02-01 13:42:10.315 14925-14925/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
02-01 13:42:10.725 14925-14942/? D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
02-01 13:42:10.784 14925-14942/? I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
02-01 13:42:10.784 14925-14942/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-01 13:42:10.784 14925-14942/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
02-01 13:42:10.785 14925-14942/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
02-01 13:42:10.785 14925-14942/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
02-01 13:42:10.810 14925-14942/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9cb60b60: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
02-01 13:42:10.872 14925-14942/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9cb60b60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa60b35d0)
02-01 13:42:10.963 14925-14942/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9cb60b60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa60b35d0)
02-01 13:42:11.480 14925-14925/com.shah.kaushal28.fence I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

MainActivity.java class

```
package com.shah.kaushal28.fence;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ResultCallback<Status>{

    private static final String TAG = "";
    protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Button mAddGeofencesButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAddGeofencesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_geofences_button);
        // Empty list for storing geofences.
        mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

        // Get the geofences used. Geofence data is hard coded in this sample.
        populateGeofenceList();

        // Kick off the request to build GoogleApiClient.
        buildGoogleApiClient();

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        Log.e(TAG, "building client successful");
    }

    public void populateGeofenceList() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : Constants.LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {
            mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId(entry.getKey())
                    .setCircularRegion(
                            entry.getValue().latitude,
                            entry.getValue().longitude,
                            Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                    )
                    .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "geofence populated");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            Log.e(TAG, "mGoogleApiClient connected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            Log.e(TAG, "mGoogleApiClient disconnected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Do something with result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void addGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google API Client not connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    getGeofencingRequest(),
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "geofence added");

    }

    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
        return builder.build();
    }

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling addgeoFences()
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
    public void onResult(Status status) {
        if (status.isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Geofences Added",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
        } else {
            // Get the status code for the error and log it using a user-friendly message.
            System.out.println("Error");
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
        }
    }
}
```

GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java class

```
package com.shah.kaushal28.fence;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofenceStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Kaushal28 on 4/26/2017.
 */

public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
    protected static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";

    public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
        super(TAG);  // use TAG to name the IntentService worker thread
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (event.hasError()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "GeofencingEvent Error: " + event.getErrorCode());
            return;
        }
        String description = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(event);
        sendNotification(description);
    }

    private static String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(GeofencingEvent event) {
        String transitionString =
                GeofenceStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(event.getGeofenceTransition());
        List triggeringIDs = new ArrayList();
        for (Geofence geofence : event.getTriggeringGeofences()) {
            triggeringIDs.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }
        return String.format("%s: %s", transitionString, TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringIDs));
    }

    private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Triggered");

        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts MainActivity.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class).addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        // Define the notification settings.
        builder.setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
                .setContentText("Click notification to return to App")
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        // Fire and notify the built Notification.
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Constants.java class

```
package com.shah.kaushal28.fence;

/**
 * Created by Kaushal28 on 4/26/2017.
 */

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.util.HashMap;


public class Constants {

    public static final long GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    public static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 20;

    public static final HashMap<String, LatLng> LANDMARKS = new HashMap<String, LatLng>();
    static {
        // San Francisco International Airport.
        LANDMARKS.put("Moscone South", new LatLng(37.783888,-122.4009012));

        // Googleplex.
        LANDMARKS.put("Japantown", new LatLng(37.785281,-122.4296384));

        // Test
        LANDMARKS.put("SFO", new LatLng(37.621313,-122.378955));
    }
}
```

Comment: GPS is kind of wildly dependant on Hardware and Location. Lots of people sit in front of their computers and wonder why their GPS code isn't working like they expect. When I was learning this stuff, I used to make GPS tracking apps and get them to notify me about places on my way to work, you can see how variable it is very quickly. Don't rely on things like Geofencing, just use them to enhance your experience

Comment: I'm testing the app on the android emulator can this be because of it.

Comment: Update your question with some of the logging you're seeing so we have an idea

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my log when testing on a real device https://drive.google.com/open?id=10Sn_BgHDKS4E0cH2H8ROAO7z8xlnwgU8

Comment: Sorry I should have said- add more logging for the geofence and show the log for when it doesn't work- i.e., something that prints out your latlong and shows that it did change etc,

Comment: Here is my log with the new updated code https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S4sXFCZp7b9MoNULkvL3sRl2mfefjbkN

Comment: That's not really useful as it's something in your start up.. log the GPS coordinates every time they change and then show that you moved into the geofence basically

Answer (score 0):

Try with bigger radius and then reduce it to the requirement -

Check google docs- https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

**Choose the optimal radius for your geofence**

For best results, the minimium radius of the geofence should be set between 100 - 150 meters. When Wi-Fi is available location accuracy is usually between 20 - 50 meters. When indoor location is available, the accuracy range can be as small as 5 meters. Unless you know indoor location is available inside the geofence, assume that Wi-Fi location accuracy is about 50 meters.

When Wi-Fi location isn't available (for example, when you are driving in rural areas) the location accuracy degrades. The accuracy range can be as large as several hundred meters to several kilometers. In cases like this, you should create geofences using a larger radius.

Comment: I changed its radius to 100 but still don't get anything

Comment: I'm testing the app on the android emulator can this be because of it.
Yes this might be the reason as you directly specify your location, may be you can check the Dwell in emulator but i am not sure.
Try with a real device..

Comment: I tried it with a real device but nothing happened too.

Comment: Have worked on this on and off for days. What a shitshow. The sample is deprecated, the docs make it seem super easy, HORRIBLE grease fire from the company that thinks they invented location management. Awful.